# Reading and Writing to Kernel Space using inpout32

Tags: python, io, hardware, kernel

Below is code I am using with python. Note that inpout32.dll which can be found [here](http://logix4u.net/Legacy_Ports/Parallel_Port/Inpout32.dll_for_Windows_98/2000/NT/XP.html) is present in the same directory.

```
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.inpout32.Out32(0x300, 40)       
print ctypes.windll.inpout32.Inp32(0x300)
```

The code should input 40 in the address of 300, however when I try to read the value at address 300 I get 255 no matter what I input. The code does however work when I use 378 as an address(LPT1).

Edit Just so everyone is aware, I am trying to do this to use an [input/output board on a 104pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158220/how-to-read-a-value-of-an-hard-coded-address-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

What model are you using? http://www.opal-rt.com/kb-article/pc104-ios-do-not-work a quick google search shows that some cards reserve 0x300, and that this is a common source of such problems.  Seems like you might be using the wrong base address.

Comment: I had a quick look through device manager and none of the cards use that address. I have also tried different base addresses.

Comment: @Richard apparently, if you use multiple cards that address is also invalid.  [source](http://www.kxcad.net/cae_MATLAB/toolbox/rtwin/ug/f11768.html#f14798)

Comment: I am just using the one board. As I mentioned before, I have also tried different base addresses.. Thanks for the suggestion though.